# Regex: Match string not containing substring not at the start of a line

Tags: regex

```
^(pause|unpause)\s+chef\s+(on\s+)?(\S+)\s+(.*)(--dryrun)?
```

I want:

```
pause chef on staging nodes AND test --dryrun
```

to match and have "nodes AND test" and "--dryrun" in two separate matching groups.

as it stands, I get "nodes AND test --dryrun" in one matching group.

I searched around and using negative lookaheads didn't seem to work for my purpose because I want anything not containing "--dryrun", but not at the beginning of the line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you made `(--dryrun)` optional by following it with `?`. Since `(.*)` is before it, that will match the longest string consistent with the rest of the expression matching, and since `--dryrun` is optional, it gobbles that up.

Use a non-greedy quantifier to make it use a shorter match.

You also need to anchor at the end of the line. Otherwise, `.*` will match the empty string after `staging`, and the optional `--dryrun` won't match anything (since it's optional).

```
^(pause|unpause)\s+chef\s+(on\s+)?(\S+)\s+(.*?)(--dryrun)?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mXj1oM/1)